# how to get auto generate id of a document in cloud firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get auto generated id of a document

> how can i getting these auto generated id's?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgui0.png

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?  Are you trying to query the database for the existing IDs?  Are you trying to create a new ID for a new document?

Comment: I'm trying to get the id's of existing documents, after getting these id i want to access the collection which is exist in these id(documents).

Comment: You have to query the collection for all the documents, then get the IDs from the snapshots in the query results. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `DataReference.push()` method of `DataReference` object.

You can see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push) for more info.

Comment: The question is asking about Firestore, not Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :-

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("MartWayDB")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                String id = document.getId();
                                //or you can store these id in array list
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error getting documents."+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

or you can follow this link :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0